# xml class not found in xml helper in cakephp

Tags: php, xml, cakephp

im getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Xml' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\wifidrivescanportal\app\View\Helper\XmlHelper.php on line 88
```

What I did is I imported the library XML class in my XML helper via these line of code:

XmlHelper.php

```
App::import('Core', array('Xml', 'Set'));
```

But still I get the same error. I have my xml library stored in this path:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\wifidrivescanportal\app\Lib\xml.php
```

BTW, inside my xml.php, ive checked that it is this class that exists:

```
class XmlNode extends Object {
// ....
}
```

Well, to make the story short, I need to utilize "serialize" of xml in cakephp. Dunno if im doing this right in the first place. Thanks for the help in advanced.

** Edit **

Ive also tried importing XML in my controller:

```
App::import('Xml');
```

yet still in the same situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your XmlHelper:

```
App::uses('Xml', 'Lib');
```

Comment: :)  thanks.. it gave me the idea..now im getting another error.. my object is not being converted to string.. im gonna research further.. thank you

Comment: This no longer works. Returns  Call to undefined method App::uses()

Answer (score 10):

Add `App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');`.

Comment: It's generally helpful to add some information as to why this solution may solve the problem rather than just feeding answers.

Comment: This one should be the answer. App::uses('Xml', 'Lib'); didn't work for me.

Comment: This no longer works. Returns  Call to undefined method App::uses()